# 「地図B」は世界中の人に平等であるように作られた

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 「地図B」は世界中の**人に平等である**ように作られた。

In this sentence, the interplay of the part in bold and the rest of the sentence is in question.

1. I learned that NOUN + に + VERB can have the meaning of doing VERBAL COMPLEX as a symbolic action in relation to NOUN, like here: "田中さんが結婚祝いにこのお皿をくださいました。"
   => Tanaka gave us this plate as present for our wedding.
   In this case 世界中の人 would fill the place of NOUN, then comes に, and then である fills the place of VERB.
2. The use of ように makes things a bit difficult for me. So far, One of the various ways of using ように seems the most probable to me:
   Verb 1 + ように + Verb 2 => Verb 1 is a means to reach Verb 2, like this:
   泳げるように毎日練習しています。("I practice every day so that I can swim")
3. So the whole sentence would read like this:
   "Concerning Map B, it was made so that there is equality for all people in the world."
   Another problem I have is that the "symbolic action" character of 平等である　isn't as clear as I think it should be. Especially if I translate "...so that there **is**...", the indicative makes it more than symbolic in my opinion. On the other hand, even in the phrase in 1, which was taken from my textbook, I do have issues with the description "symbolic action".
   Symbolic actions usually don't have a tangible manifestation, I think. At least not as tangible as a present I can touch and use etc..
   But well, maybe I'm just too picky. It's hard enough to describe language and it's still a minor issue after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've got the basic idea right. i'd have translated it as "map B was made to be fair to people throughout the world".

i think there are two things you are doing that are getting in your way. the first is that you're trying to be to be too faithful to Japanese grammar in your translation (particularly in the way you're trying to keep "map B" as a topic). Secondly, i think you're overthinking this a bit regarding the abstractness.  (omg. i can't tell you how many times i did something similar--overthinking the text--only to kick myself in the end for making it too difficult. i'm not sure how to advise you on this second point other than to be aware you might be doing it. it was a very difficult habit for me to break.)

If you're new to reading Japanese, it can help to read on topics you're already familiar with in English (or whatever other language you feel fluent in). eventually that's what i did and i found i was much better able to understand the Japanese since i was already familiar with most of the underlying topics.  and after a while i was able to tackle topics that were new to me but also of interest.

i apologize for typos. i'm on the road and responding from my cell phone. please feel free to correct.

Answer (score 1):

As for 1, your interpretation is incorrect.

Your interpretation of **に** in "田中さんが結婚祝い**に**このお皿をくださいました" is correct.
But your interpretation of **に** in "世界中の人**に**平等であるように作られた" is incorrect.

The **に** in "世界中の..." means "*for*" not "*as*", and **ある** does not mean *to exist / there is* but *so as to be* in the set phrase **であるように**, then the whole phrase may be translated like:
地図*B was made so as to be equal for all people in the world*.

I'll give you some examples using **であるように**.
- 父{ちち}**であるように**振{ふ}る舞{ま}え！　Behave so as to be a father!
- 淑女｛しゅくじょ｝**であるように**静｛しず｝かに食｛た｝べなさい。　Eat calmly so as to be a lady.

Answer (score 0):

> 「地図B」は世界中の人に平等であるように作られた。
>   This は is a object marker and 世界中の人に means "to the people of the world..."
>   So the sentence is like "the map B was made to be equal to all the people in the world."

Comment: 地図B is the subject of the sentence (as well as topic). it's not the object.

Comment: Then why you also translated the sentence in the passive voice? And How would you construe a sentence like 私はどこかを世界の中心にした地図は作らない?

Comment: i think there's some confusion going on about subject, object, and topic. in 地図は作らない, 地図 is both the topic and object of the verb. in 地図は作られた, 地図 is the topic and the subject of the verb. the subject of a passive verb is *usually* the object when the verb is active. i say usually because in both japanese and english there are odd ball cases. but that's not happening here with 作る.